# Android Studio + Gradle to create different configurations

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio and Gradle to build Android applications.  I would like to have different strings within the Java code based on which type of build it is (debug vs. release).  What is the best way to do this?

For example - I want to have different URLs if I am in debug or release.  Also, I want to specify different GUIDs and other keys / strings.

The obvious hacky way to do this is to do a search and replace of a string in AndroidManifest.xml or worse yet, in a Java file.  This approach seems error prone and hacky to me - is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways you can do this, although I usually do

```
android {
    buildTypes {

       release {
          buildConfigField("String", "URL", "your_url_on_release")
       }

       debug {
          buildConfigField("String", "URL", "your_url_on_debug")
       }
    }
}
```

You then can access them on your java code by using:

```
BuildConfig.URL
```

You can test this using Android Studio Build Variants, by changing your application variant to debug or release ( e.g. http://prntscr.com/8waxkw)

Answer (score 2):

You have many solutions to do this, here's a simple case:

```
buildTypes {
    debug { ... }
    release { ... }
}

productFlavors {
    staging { ... }
    production { ... }
}
```

- build types are for build management proguarding, debugging, signing, etc.
- productFlavors are for all app internal configuration.

If you want to add resources related to the flavours you can create and add to src/(flavor_name)/res/values/ folder your urls.xml config file.

With this, in android studio, you'll directly see, all the builds variants in the corresponding window and the right urls.xml file associated to the current context and leave the gradle config clean.

Of course, this method works also for any resource you would need in your app.

For more detail, you can read this : http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with product flavors as explained in this [post](http://antoniocappiello.com/2015/10/24/code-once-build-twice-product-flavours-at-rescue/).